# What is the default Full GC interval in Java 8

Tags: java, jboss, garbage-collection, wildfly

We noticed a strange behavior on our production server (JavaEE, Wildfly 10). The Java VM do once per hour Full GC although there is still enough memory available.

[image]

The VM start parameters are:

```
-server
-Xms4g
-Xmx8g
```

The following parameters are **not** activated:

```
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
```

So what is the default Full GC interval in Java 8 and how can I configure it to be dynamic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that

```
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
```

are not "activated".  However, those are the default values for those properties; i.e. the values that you get if you DON'T specify values for the properties.

Reference: Oracle's [sun.rmi Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html) documentation.

> So what is the default Full GC interval in Java 8

See above for the DCG triggered full GCs.

Apart from that, a full GC happens when requested (by a `System.gc()` call) or when the JVM decides it is necessary.  There is no fixed interval if you are not using RMI.

> ... and how can I configure it to be dynamic?

If you mean, how can you stop RMI from triggering a full GC every hour:

- One way is to specify (much) larger values for those properties.
- Another way is to launch the JVM with the `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` flag.  Note: this will disable *all* calls to `System.gc()` not just the calls that RMI's DGC makes.  See also: [Impact of setting -XX:+DisableExplicitGC when NIO direct buffers are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912702/impact-of-setting-xxdisableexplicitgc-when-nio-direct-buffers-are-used) for some of the problems that this may cause.
- A third way is to use `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` flag.  This reduces the impact of calls to `System.gc()`, but it will only work with GCs that support concurrent collection; e.g. CMS, G1, [ZGC](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/available-collectors.html#GUID-9E4A6B11-BB94-424F-90EF-401287A1C333) or [Shenandoah](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/shenandoah/Main).

  You can potentially tune other things to reduce the concurrent collectors "stop the world" pauses, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to set the option

```
 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
```

in combination with

```
 -XX:+UseG1GC
```

This way System.gc() will not be disabled but less harmful by making the GC work in concurrent mode instead of causing "stop the world" situations. I used this to successfully reduce my GC pauses in WildFly from 10 seconds to 500ms.